# How can I get videos to play on my Pandigital Multimedia Novel?

Tags: video

YouTube or any other videos won't play. I get music just fine but I can't seem to get videos. I have the Pandigital Multimedia Novel. What can be wrong?

Comment: Please give some useful details.  What happens?  Is there an error message?  Has it always failed to work?  Etc.

Comment: every time i try to watch youtube videos or any other videos it tells me that the web page is not available. It hasn't played one video i have tried to watch. There is no error message.  Only the web page not available page. It tells me that the webpage might be temporarily down or permanently moved to a new Web adress. It says to try watching a cached version of it by google, reload the webpage later,  or check if my device has network and data connection. I have tried all of those things and nothing works.

Comment: Hmm OK.  This is in the browser, I assume?  Do the Youtube app or local video files work?  Do you have the Flash plugin installed?

Comment: How do i check the local video files? What is the flash plugin and how would i install it? I am not completely sure if it's in the browser. I haven't tried playing anything offline because I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

I have one of these awful devices also. I will just put it simply & cut straight to the chase...it cannot play video well at all. I have rooted mine, in hopes it would play video files too, alas it is not possible. The cpu in the device is not powerful enough to handle decoding XviD (a common .avi file format), let alone higher cocmpression H.264 (.mkv files, sometimes .mp4). I use mine for an alarm clock, as it is not much more useful than this duty/task. If you're playing a mp3 file using the built-in player, and hit the HOME icon, it reboots. I had high hopes for this device, but it is just junk. I've considered selling mine on craigslist, but I don't want to dump this nightmare on anyone else either, I'm just not like that. If you want a GOOD tablet, that IS able to play most video's, get an Acer a500. You can find them refurbished now for about $250 or so. They cannot play HD video, but can play almost every regular definition file you throw at it, using BSPlayer, or Mirage beta player. I love my a500 and use it everyday, the whole family uses it in fact, and they all really enjoy it. The pandigital is nothing short of a paperweight. I have heard their other models are just as bad. The Nova is supposed to be capable of playing videos, but it has issues too. Just avoid this brand totally, and go with Acer or Samsung. Acer is much faster than Samsung, whereas the Samsung screen is a little better than the Acer. The Samsung devices are quite expensive, and most of them come with a cellular phone built in, which was something I did not want in my tablet. You can get the Acer devices at Walmart, but your best bet is ecost.com as they have them on sale right now. The 500 is a great dual core 1GHz processor, the 501 is dual core 1GHz with cell phone, the 510 is QUAD core 1Ghz, and 710 will be out soon with 1.3GHz quad core.